# If $f$ and each $f_k$ are continuous and $f_k \to f$ pointwise then $f_k \to f$ uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

I'm trying to show whether the following statement is true or not:

*If $X$ and $Z$ are matric spaces and $f_k:Z \to X$ is a sequence of continuous functions such that $f_k \to f$ pointwise (for some continuous function $f:Z \to X$)* then the sequence $(f_k)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $Z$.

---

I claim that the statement is true and here is my proof:

Let $z_0 \in Z$ and $\epsilon >0$ then there exist $\delta_1$, $\delta_2 >0$ and $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

\begin{equation}
d_X(f_k(z),f_k(z_0)) < \frac{\epsilon}{3}, \text{ if } \  d_Z(z,z_0)< \delta_1 \\
d_X(f(z),f(z_0)) < \frac{\epsilon}{3}, \text{ if } \ d_Z(z,z_0)< \delta_2 \\
d_X(f_k(z_0), f(z_0)) < \frac{\epsilon}{3}, \text{ if } \ k \geq k_0
\end{equation}

So by taking $\delta = \max(\delta_1, \delta_2)$, $k \geq k_0$ and $d_Z(z,z_0)<\delta$ we get:

$$ d_Z(f_k(z),f(z)) \leq d_Z(f_k(z),f_k(z_0))+d_Z(f_k(z_0),f(z))+d_Z(f(z),f(z_0))<\epsilon$$

My question is the following: To prove uniform convergence the definition must be satisfied for all $z \in Z$, however my argument only considers those $z$ close to a fixed $z_0$. Could it be argued that since $z_0$ was arbitrary this works for all $z \in Z$? or How could I prove the uniform convergence?

Comment: $Z=X=\mathbb R$ and $f_k=\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{x^j}{j!}, f=\exp x$. Check that it does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Counterexamples: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411191/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1280953/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2246626/42969 (found with a Google search for “pointwise but not uniform convergence”)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2849870/does-pointwise-convergence-to-a-continuous-function-on-a-closed-interval-imply-u